# php - very granulated user privileges

Tags: php, privileges

I am currently building an application for multiple users and have gotten to the user privileges part.

The application consists of about 20ish submenu items and each should be granted/denied access to for each user depending on the user privileges.

This means a user A could have access to submenu 1,4 and 21, user B to submenu 2,3,9,11,20 etc etc

This means that it would be impossible to make every single combination into user roles so i have thought about a simple solution.

My first idea was to save the access level into a string.

This way, i could use a charactor index in that string for each submenu to test against.

Although this might work, I would say it is going to become messy really fast so my question is.

What is the best way to get around this problem? I am looking for something that is maintainable and intuitive without needing a million new tables on the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use hexadecimals mixed with OR opeartion all together. the result will be the permission string. once u need to add another permission, you just add another exadecimal and it's done. you have to build hexadecimals like this 0x1000000, 0x2000000, 0x4000000,  0x8000000

Comment: Before you get as low-level as *string indexes*... what is the logic?! Is it really a one-by-one individual user-to-item permission level? Then an appropriate many-to-many relational database table is probably the answer.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)?

Comment: axel - Not quiet sure how to go about doing that, just save the hexdecimals in the database and check them on a user request?

deceze - if i understand you correctly, yes, the user privileges are individual and range from nothing to everything per user

complex857 - The problem with a conventual way of doing this, i would have to make a role for every single possible option and that would be waaaaay too many

Comment: yes, example `const PERMISSION_1 = 0x1000000; const PERMISSION_2 = 0x2000000;const PERMISSION_3 = 0x4000000;` / then you save permissions of a user with OR opeator `$sPermissionUser = PERMISSION_1 | PERMISSION_2; ` / then you check if the user has permission `if($sPermissionUser & PERMISSION_2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing the point here but, couldn't each submenu have a ID and then have a join table between ID and User ID which determines access, you could and another column to that join table for access level (read-only, edit, admin, etc).

depending on required performance you could cache that response for a user after the first access request or you could look it up on every sub menu request.